# How to bypass proxy in iOS programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, swift, network-programming

These are my steps

Network is available now for the Wifi.

Open system WiFi settings

Select manual proxy settings

Configure invalid parameters

Open browser and make sure that internet is not available

Start the app and make sure there is no internet

Is there any way that programmatically from inside the app, I can bypass those proxy settings so that I can connect to the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encounter your problem in 2018, after some time digging in the document found the key kCFStreamPropertyProxyLocalBypass for setting in the proxy dictionary.
fyi:https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cfnetwork/kcfstreampropertyproxylocalbypass

**Objective-C**

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

NSDictionary *proxyDict = @{
                        @"HTTPEnable"  : [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                        (NSString *)kCFStreamPropertyProxyLocalBypass  : @"10.26.*.*",              
                        @"HTTPSEnable" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                       (NSString *)kCFStreamPropertyProxyLocalBypass  : @"10.26.*.*"
                          };
sessionConfig.connectionProxyDictionary = proxyDict;
```

**Swift**

```
let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
var proxyDict = [AnyHashable : Any]()
proxyDict[kCFStreamPropertyProxyLocalBypass as String] = "10.26.*.*"
sessionConfig.connectionProxyDictionary = proxyDict
let session = URLSession.init(configuration: config, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.current)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [CFHTTPStream](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFHTTPStreamRef/), which by default does not automatically use the proxy settings.

For more information, read the [CFNetwork Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html).